# Use of Inception v3 model for Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I have used Tensorflow Object Detection API suuccessfuly by using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017` model.

Now I need to use Inception v3 model instead of mobilenet model.

**Question:**

can I use it for Tensorflow Object Detection API and how can I change the config file and how to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can refer ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config file. it is used to give configuration for the Tensorflow object detection API. you can edit it and give modifications as you want.